# How to write Unit Test for a function which uses a variable defined in Constructor

Tags: magento2, testing, unit-tests, phpunit

I'm trying to write a Unit Test in Magento 2 which uses a variable defined in `__construct()`. The variable gets its value in another function. Thus when I run my test it gives me an error that the variable is null. How can I feed a value to that variable in my test to make it pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In unit tests you test components isolated. That means that you should construct the objects under test yourself and provide input by the test, not by some external method.

#### Example:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider dataAddTwoNumbers
 */
public function testItAddsTwoNumbers($number1, $number2, $expectedResult)
{
    $addition = new Addition($number1, $number2);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $addition->result());
}
public static function dataAddTwoNumbers()
{
    return [
        [1, 1, 2],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [-1, 1, 0],
    ];
}
```

If you need other classes that would be instantiated by the object manager, instantiate them yourself, or create a stub/mock. Let's say, your `Addition` class needs the `StoreManagerInterface` and calls `getStore()` on it (for whatever reason), then the code could look like this:

```
$store = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface::class)
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();

$storeManager = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class)
    ->setMethods(['getStore'])
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();
$storemanager->method('getStore')->willReturn($store);

$addition = new Addition($storeManager, $number1, $number2);
```

---

If you want to test that it gets the right values and interacts correctly with the framework or other components, write an **integration test**, this is not the job of the unit test.